# The intersection of non-empty ,nested, and compact sets, subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not empty

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Well I need to show that if $A_1\supset A_2\supset\ldots$ are compact and nonempty in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $\bigcap_i A_i \not=\emptyset$, but I think there is something wrong, because $\bigcap_i A_i= A_k$ with $A_k$ the minimum of the $A_i$ and since this is not empty the we got the result, but I think this isn't right, can you help me to prove this correctly please ? thanks in advance.

**What would happened is the A were only closed?**

**well I think I got it, if the intersection is not empty then it should exists a element that belong to $A_i$ for all $i$ but by the nesting property I can not happened :) right ?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that "$A_k$ is the *minimum* of the $A_i$? What if there is no *minimum* among the $A_i$?

Comment: well that was my preliminar idea :), that is why I got confused with my above proof :)

Comment: You didn't answer my question of what you meant by *minimum*.

Comment: Look at the complements of the $A_k$ and use the definition of compactness.

Comment: but the complements are open right how can I use compactness

Comment: The statement in your title is false. It would be best to use a more precise title.

Answer (score 5):

If the intersection is empty, then the complements of $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots$ would be an open cover of $A_1.$  It would then have a finite subcover $A_1^C,\ldots,A_n^C$. So
$$
A_1^C\cup\cdots\cup A_n^C \supseteq A_1,
$$
$$
A_1 \cap\cdots\cap A_n\subseteq A_1^C.
$$
But that is clearly false.

Comment: ok then you use compactness when you say that  complements of A1,A2,A3,… would be an open cover of A1. It would then have a finite subcover AC1,…,ACn.

Comment: @user162343 The nesting property is critical here-without it,the proof is nonsense.

Comment: what is the nesting property?

Comment: @user162343 : The "nesting property" is the initial assumption $A_1\supset A_2\supset\cdots$.  One says these sets are "nested", or more verbosely, they are linearly ordered by inclusion. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: ok but then I am right, isn't, whenn I say that compactness was used to say that  It would then have a finite sub cover ...

Comment: What would happened is the A were only closed?

Comment: well I think I got it, if the intersection is not empty then it should exists a element that belong to $A_i$ for all $i$ but by the nesting property I can not happened :) right ?

Comment: @user162343 : Yes.  It is because $A_1$ is compact that we concluded there is a finite subcover.

Comment: And what about if they are only closed

Comment: If each of the sets were required to be closed but not required to be compact, then we could have $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left([n,\infty)\times\mathbb R^{n-1}\right)$, which is empty. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Then de are done with this right ?

Comment: can you explain me more your above comment please :)

Comment: @user162343 : I'm not sure exactly what you want to know about my last comment.  Notice that $[1,\infty)\cap[2,\infty)\cap[3,\infty)\cap\cdots=\varnothing$. This is a decreasing sequence of closed sets whose intersection is empty. With compact sets, that doesn't happen.  Since you said you wanted this to be in $\mathbb R^n$, I took the Cartesian product of each of these sets with $\mathbb R^{n-1}$.  And my notation wasn't good; I should have written $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty\left([k,\infty)\times\mathbb R^{n-1}\right)$, rather than using the letter $n$ for two different things.

Comment: Good, then this an exampme of that the result fails :)