# Cantor set as $\bigcap_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$

Tags: general-topology

Could someone clarify me over a doubt I have encountered. When we have a decreasing sequence of sets $\{E_n\}$. The set $E_n$ is compact. According to a thorem $\bigcap_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ is non-empty.If the set was open it would be empty? Is $\bigcap_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ the cantor set? If not, why not? Thanks for reading.

Comment: According to which theorem? Consider $\mathbb N$ with the trivial topology and $E_n = \{k:k>n\}$, now $\bigcap E_n$ is empty despite $E_n$ being compact. Also there are cases wher $E_n$ is open and still the intersection is non-empty. For example let $E_n = \{x: |x|<1+1/n\}$ with the standard topology of $\mathbb R$. Also there's no guarantee that $\bigcap E_n$ being the cantor set, it may be, but also it may not be.

Comment: $\bigcap_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ is not empty because the null set is open and $\bigcap_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ is closed.

Comment: But the empty set is also closed so there's nothing then hindering $\bigcap E_n$ to be empty, see also  my counter example. In addition there's nothing saying that $\bigcap E_n$ is closed either, using the trivial topology in $\mathbb R$ and consider $E_n = \{x: |x|=0 \lor x>n\}$ you have $\bigcap E_n = \{0\}$ which is not closed.

Comment: @skyking it is closed if all $E_n$ are closed. but not necessarily non-empty.

Comment: Empty set is open. If the empty set was closed it would be forced to have points, which is a contradiction. Imagine we have an open set X, difined on an algebra $Q$ that has $(X,\emptyset)$. If $X=(3,5)$, $X^c\neq\emptyset$ because if it did the empty set would have the 3 and 5 numbers. Am I right?

Comment: @PedroGomes No the empty set is also always closed. A set is closed if and only if it's complement is open and a set is open if and only if it's part of the topology and the topology is required to contain the empty set and the whole space. This means that the whole space and empty set are always both open and close. You need to review your knowledge on basic topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That's correct, but there was no requirement that $E_n$ was closed, they were only required to be compact. In the trivial topology all sets are compact (since the only cover of a non-empty set only can contain the entire space which makes every open cover of a set finite and then it will have a finite subcover). Basically the argument for the intersection is non-empty is flawed in many ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sets $E_n$ would have been merely open, yes, the intersection could have been empty (in general). There is no theorem garanteeing that $\cap E_n \neq \emptyset$ for a decreasing sequence of non-empty open sets, or closed sets either.

The intersection is the Cantor set by definition yes. (if you use the standard $E_n$, finite unions of closed intervals).

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "There is np theorem garanteeing that 
$\bigcap E_n\neq\emptyset$ for a decreasing sequence of non-empty open sets, or closed sets for neither"? If the set is compact it cannot be empty right?

Comment: What does np stand for?

Comment: @PedroGomes typo fixed. If the $E_n$ are compact, the intersection is non-empty if all $E_n$ are.

Comment: That is because the empty set is open, right?

Comment: @PedroGomes nothing to do with the emptyset being open, I think. It's jsut a theorem which holds for compact closed sets. (and in the reals compact sets are automatically closed.)

Comment: I saw the proof of that theorem in this forum making use of the fact the empty set is opened.

Comment: @PedroGomes link?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133807/the-intersection-of-non-empty-nested-and-compact-sets-subsets-of-mathbbr

Comment: @PedroGomes the first answer only uses compactness and closedness of the sets.

Comment: @PedroGomes The proof uses that in $\mathbb R^2$ all compact sets are closed. This is not true in general however: with the trivial topology any set is compact, but only two sets are closed. As shown there's examples where the claim fails for other topological spaces. If you want to generalize the theorem you would have to say that $A_n$ should be non-empty, closed **and** compact, then the proof works in any topological space.